# Use variable in .map function javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a `map` function and would like to pass in a variable as a `Key` such that the `obj.item` below takes the variable `Salary` to become `Salary` as the `key` instead of `item`.

```
weeklyData.map(function(obj) {
        var day = obj.day;
        var item = "Salary";
        if (day === "Day") {
          obj.item = "text"; // obj.item should be Salary as key
          obj = obj;
        };
        return obj;
      });
```

Comment: `item` is a string when did it changed to an object `item.text`?

Comment: I modified my real code, item is actually an object I used, edited above

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors#Bracket_notation)

```
obj[item] = "text";
```

This will set the key to whatever `item` holds, in your case `Salary`.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
weeklyData.map(function(obj) {
        var day = obj.day;
        var item = "Salary";
        if (day === "Day") {
          obj[item] = "text";
        };
        return obj;
});
```

You don't need this line `obj = obj;`, you are working with the object reference.